# how to get the owner name of a data extension in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, dataextensions, soap-api

Is there any way to get the owner of a DE through API or Query?, Currently we have a SOAP API but this is not bringing us the Owner, this would be the only attribute that does not call

Comment: DE owner isn't really a concept unless you mean MID the DE is in?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to extract the information from a DE, among those fields is the owner of the DE according to this documentation, it can be extracted in this way or it just can't be done? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/dataextension.html

Comment: @EazyE the owner is the person who created the DE and it’s visible in the UI. Unfortunately haven’t tried retrieving it via API.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the SOAP documentation.  It's very inaccurate and often misleading.  It's better to DESCRIBE a SOAP objects and try to retrieve every property.  Then remove those that are reported as non-retrievable.  Both the DESCRIBE and RETRIEVE can be done easily in Postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible to retrieve it with currently available endpoints and methods. All in all, Owner field is found but non-retrievable. Here is what I have tried:

1. REST API:

`GET https://[domain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/[External Key]/rowset` - Retrieves Data Extension data from Custom Object looked up by External Key. Not documented endpoint.

**Result:** does not mention Owner field at all

2. [SSJS Data Extension Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dataExtensionRetrieve.html):

```js
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1")
var Retrieve = DataExtension.Retrieve({Property: "Name", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "xxx"});
var Owner = Retrieve[0].Owner;
Write(Stringify(Owner));
</script>
```

**Result:** variable Owner returns NULL value

3. [SSJS WSProxy Data Extension Retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.html):

```js
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1")
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = ["CustomerKey", "Name", "Owner"];
var filter = {Property: "Name", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "xxx"};
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter);
Write(Stringify(data));
</script>
```

**Result:** returns `"Error: The Request Property(s) Owner do not match with the fields of DataExtension retrieve"`

4. [SSJS WSProxy Data Extension object Describe:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_WSProxy_describe.html)

```js
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1")
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var data = prox.describe("DataExtension");
Write(Stringify(data));
</script>
```

**Result:** Owner property is not retrievable, thus nothing you can do.

Comment: Agree.  Owner isn't retrievable on any SOAP object, AFAIK.  Other API objects retrievable via REST use the `createdBy.id` property.  Consistency on those isn't great either.